# Laravel 5.4 edit login query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to add a where clause to the standard laravel login query, like

`Select * from users where function = "Admin"`,

so basically only Admins can LogIn into the application.

My question is, in which file can I add this?

Comment: You should create a logincontroller, that uses that eloquent condition `User::query()->where()` username = username, pw = pw, function = admin

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middleware to your route group so that only admin users can access the routes in that group.

You should go through the documentation first. The authorization and authentication provided by Laravel will meet your needs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware